# Maven Specify Source Location

Tags: java, maven, svn, intellij-idea

Is there a way to tell maven where your sources are locally in a `pom.xml` with a relative path?  We have lots of projects in our SVN repo, and locally I mirror the repository.  In my IntelliJ IDEA I can do this and modify my local source code for a foreign dependency and its quite useful in some situations.

To be clear this is different from [Can I configure sources location for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361683/can-i-configure-sources-location-for-maven) in two ways.  One its a few years later in time and two I want to use sources already existing locally that share the same relative path as in SVN.

My question is also different from I see that you can tell maven to download sources uploaded to your repository in this post [Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository) because I dont want to involve our maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 directions for your question.

**Direction I.** Create own repostitory (It also called *corporate repository*)

1. Create own maven repository
See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html ---> at section: *Internal Repositories*.

2. Inform IntelliJ IDEA use own repository in pom.xml file by figure out your repository address.

**Direction II.** 
You want IntelliJ IDEA doesn't download existing artifacts from internet.
Yes, **If artifacts are existing. IntelliJ IDEA import to your project automatically. You don't need do anything.**

Local repository at: `...\.m2\repository`   (3 dots at the start, in Windows operating system only).

You also maybe want put your artifacts to `...\.m2\repository`, and must follow Maven's predefined structure.